# How can I use my own image as prev/next arrow in slick.js?

Tags: css, icons, carousel, slick.js

This is what I have right now :

[image]

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/6xnax028/1/) : when I use font-awesome

[`JSFiddle_2`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/6xnax028/2/) : when I tried use image background

Currently, I use font-awesome for the arrows, and now I want to load my own icon instead.

I tried this, but no luck:

I've been struggling for quite a while now. I hope someone can help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Image line doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110227180545/callofduty/images/archive/3/36/20110227205839!Right_arrow.png

Comment: Which responds "Unrecognized request path! See [https://github.com/Wikia/vignette] for documentation."

Comment: Still doesn't work for you ? I'm very curious. I even try to use my local image, it won't display also.

Comment: @Paulie_D : When I tried using the `background-image` my arrows is gone completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically all you need to do is change the `content` property of the pseudo elements to the appropriate image url(s).

```
.slick-next:before {
    content:url(http://lorempixel.com/20/20/);
}
.slick-prev:before {
    content:url(http://lorempixel.com/20/20/);
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/6xnax028/3/)

Comment: May I ask why not using background-image ? but content instead. I'm just curious. It works. You're right. !

Comment: I don't need to use a background image...this is much cleaner. BUT...note that the size of the pseudo element is the size of the image. If you want to use a bg image, you would have to set a size of the pseudo element. otherwise it collapses which is why your bg image may not show (other than the access issues already mentioned)

Comment: Precise explanation. Thanks again. You're rock.